# How to count algebraic multiplicities to show $\nexists$ an eigenbasis for $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix},f_A(\lambda)=(1-\lambda)^3 \,\text{and } E_1=\text{ker }\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}=\text{span }\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\right\}, \\\text{i.e. } \lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3=1 \,\text{such that all algebraic multiplicities are 3 },\,\text{but dim}(E_1)=1|\sum(\text{dim}(E_{\lambda_{i}}))=3=\text{almu }(\lambda_{i}).$

---

How do I prove that $\nexists$ an eigenbasis for $A$? I thought that showing that the sum of the geometric multiplicities $\neq n $ would be sufficient, but I'm finding that they are the same. I know intuitively that given $\text{ker}(A-\lambda I_n), \nexists\,$ an eigenbasis, but I'm having trouble showing that this logically follows from the definition. How would I make this explicit? Does this have to do with how we "count" the algebraic multiplicities for each $\lambda_{i}$?

Comment: Calculate the eigenvectors and point out that there are too few eigenvectors to form a basis.

Comment: ahh, I see. the eigenvectors can't form a basis because they are the same vector, i.e. they are not linearly independent?

Comment: Kind of, but to me, that's a bit strange way of seeing it. Rather, you have only one eigenvector, not three that are equal. But yes, you need three (linearly independent) vectors to span $\mathbb R^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are practically done - If $B=\{v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}\}$ is a basis
of eigenvectors then $v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}$ are all eigenvectors that
correspond to the eigenvalue $1$ (since this is the only eigenvalue).

But the eigenspace of the eigenvalue $1$ has dimension $1$, hence it
cannot contain $3$ linearly independent vectors.